# Combine two urls into one in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to combine two urls into a single url.

```
var access_token = 138def4a4e;
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/app/?access_token=";
```

I want the final url to be:

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/app/?access_token=[access_token]";
```

How to do that in node.js? I tried using url. Resolve but it was of no use.

pls help
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your code looks like this:

```
var access_token = '138def4a4e'
var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/app/?access_token='
```

If so, the answer is:

```
var combined = url + access_token
```

For a final answer of:

```
var access_token = '138def4a4e'
var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/app/?access_token='
url += access_token
console.log(url)
```

Comment: thanks,it helped. the method i used is 
access_token = '138def4a4e';
url_1 = "https://graph.facebook.com/app/?access_token=";
url = url_1 + access_token;
and it worked absolutely fine.
Thanks again.

Comment: This implementation, in general, is very unsafe. Consider using URL object and its capabilities to build and manipulate URLs.

Answer (score 5):

As noted above the selected solution is unsafe.

The following snippet should be preferred:

```
const accessToken = '138def4a4e';
const someValidUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/app/?foo=bar'; // note the querystring param
const url = new URL(someValidUrl);
url.searchParams.append('access_token', accessToken);
console.log(url.href);
```

As you can notice it's able to manage an Url that contains query parameters and the URLencoding of the querystring params.